A question about the inverse of Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem
Suppose that $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $r < n$. Consider the following problem:
$\min ||X - Y||_F$
s.t. $\ rank(X)\leq r$
Let $\mathcal{B}_r$ be the solution set of the above problem. Suppose the SVD of $Y$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
Y =
\begin{bmatrix}
 U_r&U_{n-r}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_r & 0 \\
0        & \Sigma_{n-r}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 V_r^{\top} \\
 V_{n-r}^{\top}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where the singular values are in descending order.
Then by Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem, we know that:
\begin{equation}
 Y_r = U_r\Sigma_r V_{r}^{\top}
\end{equation}
is a solution of the above problem, i.e. $Y_r\in\mathcal{B}_r$.
Now my question is: let $\bar{X}\in\mathcal{B}_r$ be any solution of the above problem, is there must be a SVD of $Y$:
\begin{equation}
Y =
\begin{bmatrix}
 \bar{U}_r&\bar{U}_{n-r}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_r & 0 \\
0        & \Sigma_{n-r}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \bar{V}_r^{\top} \\
 \bar{V}_{n-r}^{\top}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
such that $\bar{X} = \bar{U}_r\Sigma_r \bar{V}_{r}^{\top}?$

Yes $ $ $ $ $ $

Thank you. Can you be more specific? If $\bar{X}$ is already given, how to derive $ \bar{U}_r $ and $\bar{V}_r$.
